# Looking for a medium power optocoupler

Tags: opto-isolator, isolation, lamp

I have a project where I will control a 3 or 6 watt UV lamp *DC* with a microcontroller.

I want to power my lamps with a *AC/DC* circuit and switch them on and off with a optocoupler, mainly because optocoupler uses very low current and is physically separated from the high voltage circuit. My only worry is that my optocoupler is not going to handle the 3W or 6W lamp.

**What optocoupler do you think would do the best job for this project?**

I was looking at **4N35** optocoupler and in Its [datasheet](http://measure.feld.cvut.cz/groups/edu/osv/4n35.pdf) I was having trouble finding the max power that can go through the transistor of this optocoupler.

Another question that I have is **Do I need to use relay istead of optocoupler for dealing with this kind of power ( *3W 6W* )?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably won't find an opto-coupler that will do the job. The switching voltage and current is just too much. I'd consider a triac to buffer the opto output. This is the normal sort of component for this type of application. Of course, if you can use a relay, that's conceptually the easiest and the most unlikely to get your fingers burned on.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to switch on/off a lamp load that's a UV lamp from a microcontroller. You say that the lamp will be powered from DC but I'm only aware of AC UV lamps. No problem though.

It's very unlikely that you'll find a part that's *directly* suitable but a circuit containing an opto-triac coupled to a discrete triac should do the job.

Here are a couple of design examples.

[image: optically coupled triac with snubber network]

[image: without snubber]

The snubber network is recommended to suppress switch off transients. Less of a problem with 'zero-crossing' parts that only switch on/off at current reversals.

Image sources are ...

https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhYfe.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSEgC.gif

Original authors unknown but likely from vendor's application notes.

Comment: Could you please provide links or citations for the graphics you have included in your answer? We want to be sure to give credit to the original creator.

Comment: Understood. I can probably locate them again. In what way should I credit them ? By the link (which I was trying to avoid) or site ?

Comment: Here are the site's guidelines: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: Thanks, I'd actually been looking for such advice but hadn't yet found it. I'll add the reference.

Answer (score 0):

6W / 120V RMS =  50mA RMS

Any solid state relay that has an allowed load voltage greater than 170V peak and a current rating of 50mA RMS or better would work.  Of course if you want it to work reliably you should add some margin to that.

There are plenty of solid state relays that would meet your requirements.

One example is...

Panasonic AQH0223AZ

https://b2b-api.panasonic.eu/file_stream/pids/fileversion/2787

It costs $1.06 each and is rated for 600V, 300mA.  Typical drive current is 15mA on the control side.

Comment: Another sensible suggestion. Larger SSRs are packaged with lug terminals and are  'ready to go' and require no design. A random instance is .. https://www.rapidonline.com/i-autoc-kudom-ksim380d10-l-pnl-mnt-ssr-4-32vdc-48-440vac  -10a-load-led-zero-cross-60-1597